# json encoding php for fetching the data from the database ang showing it to te graph

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have written the following code for fetching the data from the database:

```
$result = mysql_query("select projid,projname,enddate,status from projects where kunnr='".$_SESSION["kunnr"]."'");
$model['dash']=array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    array_push($model['dash'],
        array(
            "id"=>$row["projid"],
            "projname"=>$row["projname"],
            "enddate"=>$row["enddate"],
            "status"=>$row["status"],

        ));
}

and the following code for showing these data on the graph(chart)..
$(document).ready(function() {
      chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
         chart: {
            renderTo: 'container1',
            type: 'column'
         },
         title: {
            text: 'Service Calls-Days Over'
         },
         xAxis: {
            categories:[ <?php foreach($model["dashchart"] as &$obj){?>
                           '<?php echo $obj["name"];?>',
                           <?php }?>]
         },
         yAxis: {


         },
         series: [{
            name: 'Service Calls-Days Over',
            color:'#e48801',
            data: [<?php foreach($model["dashchart"] as &$obj){?>
                     <?php echo  $obj["days"];?>,
                           <?php }?>]
         }
         ]
      });
```

overhere i have used php coding but i want to do it by json encoding..
please suggest me...

Comment: Those two code snippets are only loosely related. The fetching part stores something in $model['dash'] while the display part reads data from $model['dashchart']

Comment: yes the real code for this is as follows:

Answer (score 0):

use json_encode.. 
For example:

```
categories: <?php echo json_encode($model["dashchart"]); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with jQuery.getJSON http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/  function.